# How to Allow users to sign in with phone number in one model and from email in another devise_auth_token rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-api

I am using devise_auth_token for authentication in rails-api.
I want to allow users to sign in with their on phone number for that

```
config.authentication_keys = [:phone]
```

But issue is that I have another model using devise and its signin is from email how I differentiate them with each other?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set authentication_keys on the model itself, like :-

class model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :authentication_keys => [:email]
end

class model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :authentication_keys => [:phone]
end